# Is it normal for instantaneous GLOC to occur at 5 G's?

Tags: medical, aerobatics

Is it normal for a trainee to have an instantaneous G-force induced loss of consciousness (GLOC) at 4-5 G's in a light military trainer aircraft like Socata TB 30 Epsilon, after doing a manoeuvre sequence?

Comment: Did you follow your training and were you wearing a G suit?

Comment: Wasn't me but a comrade who started training about 4 months ago. In Portuguese Air Force trainees don't wear anti G suit in this formation phase and in that particular aircraft. He did AGSM, but i cannot be sure if correctly executed...

Answer (score 6):

That sounds really unlikely to be a G-LOC.  That usually happens at much higher loadings after 3-4 seconds of straining.  The counscious and cognitive centers of the brain take a few seconds to shut down once the systolic and diastolic pressures hit zero in the brain.  It may be an indication of another underlying medical issue.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that doesn't sound normal.  I didn't strain unless I was pulling in excess of 4 and never experienced any ill effects.  I also never had a student GLOC and we would pull north of 6g's pretty routinely.  They should definitely be checked out medically.

I will caveat this because you used the word instantaneous.  It would not be unusual in my opinion for your student to go to sleep if they were pulling a sustained 5g's and were not correctly using their g-strain.  Every person's resting g-tolerance is different, and can be higher or lower on any given day based on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, there should be signs of oxygen deprival before full loss of consciousness. In my experience, first the field of sight narrows down as if someone drew a curtain in the eyes (tunnel vision), and then you go totally blind. This would happen to me at maybe 1 g less than usual when preceded by inverted flying, but still only above 4 g. Hearing and reasoning are not yet affected - for this it needs more gs.

How many depends on how long the load factor lasts and on general health. Training also helps, as do breathing techniques like the [anti-g straining maneuver](http://goflightmedicine.com/agsm/). From an [FAA brochure](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/safety/pilotsafetybrochures/media/Acceleration.pdf) on this topic:

> This is a physical technique where the aviator pushes air out of the lungs against
>   a closed glottis, while simultaneously contracting
>   the muscles in the calves, thighs, and shoulders.  is resistance inhibits the blood from  owing away from the brain, and it simultaneously increases the pressure in the carotid arteries.

Instantaneous G-LOC is only possible with very rapid rates of g increase to a level above 6 to 8. At 4-5 gs this should not happen to a healthy person. I would recommend to see a physician about this.